# Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported (using Monaca for Apache Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, monaca

I'm trying to build my Apache Cordova app for android and I face with this error. I found that *android:exported="true"*  must be added to the activity attributes but since I am using many cordova-plugins which add different activity attribute to the AndroidManifest.xml it is impossible to change all of them manually.
I want to know does anyone have any solution for this problem?
Note: For using new plugins I cannot downgrade my sdk target version to 30 an I must use 31.

Error code:

```
    [17:39:47] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[17:39:47] * What went wrong:
[17:39:47] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[17:39:47] Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
[17:39:47] > Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
[17:39:47] * Try:
[17:39:47] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[17:39:47] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[17:39:47] You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
[17:39:47] See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[17:39:47] 14 actionable tasks: 14 executed
[17:39:47] BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
[17:39:47] Command failed with exit code 1: /tmp/download/platforms/android/gradlew :app:bundleRelease -b /tmp/download/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

Comment: Try update Gradle to 7.5.1. Works for me